# Using JNA to link to custom dll

Tags: java, dll, jna

how do I access custom .lib / .dll functions using JNA?
Can someone provide an example?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Example ([from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access#Example)):

```
import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;
import com.sun.jna.Native;

/** Simple example of Windows native library declaration and usage. */
public class BeepExample {
   public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {
       // FREQUENCY is expressed in hertz and ranges from 37 to 32767
       // DURATION is expressed in milliseconds
       public boolean Beep(int FREQUENCY, int DURATION);
       public void Sleep(int DURATION);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Kernel32 lib = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", 
           Kernel32.class);
    lib.Beep(698, 500);
    lib.Sleep(500);
    lib.Beep(698, 500);
   }
}
```

In this case, we load it from the "kernel32.dll" library.
I hope this makes JNA clearer.

EDIT: I'll explain the code:
You need to define an interface(that extends com.sun.jna.Library) with the functions you need from the library.
Then, call com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary("LibraryName", InterfaceName.class).
Finally, store the output in a variable with the type of the interface.
Just call the functions from that variable.

Comment: You should be extending StdCallLibrary for the specific example you gave.  Whether or not it applies to the user's custom library depends on what calling convention that library uses.

Comment: how to provide path for my custom dll I mean if my dll lies somewhere in e:/Mydll. then how to provide the path and if Mydll made using some other dll and library then do i need to provide path somewhere for these dll also ?

Comment: You should ether add the path to your dll or lib to your path environment variable or add the path to the class path argument.