# How to access a DLL file in java?

Tags: java, dll, vb6, java-native-interface

I have some methods in a Visual Basic 6.0 DLL that I need to access in Java 6.0. How do I do this?

Answer (score 7):

The [Java Native interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) is your friend. But the easier way should be using the Java Native Access library. [Here's an answer to a similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492567/using-jna-to-link-to-custom-dll).

Answer (score 1):

JNI can be easily used to access any function publicly available in a DLL (managed or unmanaged) so that it can be used in java.

You will need to create your own interface, using Java Native Interface (JNI), and then call the interface functions as you normally do.